# sitemap_7.php file found via Google Fetch, can't find/access in browser/FTP/SSH

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm pulling my hair out right now and I can't seem to narrow down this hack.

Google Fetch & Render inside Webmaster Tools is finding a /sitemap_7.php file on our server that just isn't there -- in either the files via the browser/ftp/ssh.

http://www.designbeeadvertising.com/sitemap_7.php

I've scanned the site in every way I can. I just can't find the file.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post the content of your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out the syntax formatting so I just put it in a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/wdrq7u3y/1/

Comment: What exactly is the content of the file when rendered by the Google Webmaster Tools? Is it malware? Or is it just a random file? I see that you are denying access in the `.htaccess` file, but I'm trying to understand why you came across this in the first place to see if I have any ideas on how to fix it.